# Sorting values of ObservableCollection (Reactive Extensions)

Tags: c#, windows-8, system.reactive

In my application i am having a list with more than 400 push pins. For avoiding the UI block i am using the following terminolagy along with Rx framework.

```
var observer = localStoreCollection.ToObservable();
observer.Subscribe(StoresOnNext, StoresOnError, StoresOnCompleted);
```

On the OnNext i will add this pushpins one by one to my binding list. Along with the map i am populating a list with the same collection. So i need to sort this list based on the nearest location. So my question is how i can sort this collection without re assigning the list. (Kind of stuff similar to call by reference).

NB : Also the assigning of distance is made inside the OnNext method.

Comment: What is `StoresOnNext` etc? Are you trying to simply have an observable of the object with the lowest value of some metric (distance)?

Comment: StoreNext will iterate each value of  localStoreCollection, So in OnNext i will add that push pin into my binding observabel collection.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that means. Could you perhaps include the rest of the code. What StoresOnNext is etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark here since I have no idea what you are asking...

edit...just read your question again with the NB. Now generally speaking I would advise HIGHLY against the concept of using functional programming to assign values your data objects. Instead I would advise you either create a new object which includes your PushPin and a Distance property OR you use a map to store the distance information as a kind of "Extension Property".

```
var observer = localStoreCollection.ToObservable();
observer.Subscribe(StoresOnNext, StoresOnError, StoresOnCompleted);
var closestObservable = observer.Min(Comparer<PushPin>.Create((a, b) => Double.Comparer(Distance(a), Distance(b)));
```

Or possibly even

```
var observer = localStoreCollection.ToObservable();
observer.Subscribe(StoresOnNext, StoresOnError, StoresOnCompleted);
var distanceMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<PushPin, double>();
var closestObservable = observer.Min(Comparer<PushPin>.Create((a, b) => Double.Comparer(distanceMap.GetOrAdd(a, Distance), distanceMap.GetOrAdd(b, Distance)));
```

if the `Distance(PushPin)` function is expensive.